# How do you interpret the coefficient of a growth variable when the dependent variable is also a growth variable?

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, descriptive-statistics, macroeconomics

How do you interpret a coefficient of $\beta=0.0307 $ in this model?

$ \frac { \Delta Y _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } } { Y _ { t } ^ { i j } } = \mu _ { j } + \beta \frac { \Delta P _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } } { P _ { t } ^ { i j } } + \epsilon _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } $

Where $i$ is neighbourhood, $j$ is city, $\mu_{j}$ is city fixed effects, $t=2001$, $k=5$, $\epsilon _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } $ is the error term, $\frac { \Delta Y _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } } { Y _ { t } ^ { i j } }$ is the growth of median wages and $\frac { \Delta P _ { t ,t + k } ^ { i j } } { P _ { t } ^ { i j } }$ is the growth of house prices from $2001$ to $2006$.

P.S. sorry for the simple question I'm new to econometrics.